# document.createElement is a Proxy in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to parse a page using Puppeteer. However, one of the scripts on the page is attempting to override the `createElement` property of the document object, and this is causing an error. The error message is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'createElement' of object '#<HTMLDocument>'`

After looking into it, I've realized that `document` properties in Puppeteer are safeguarded by proxy objects.

When I run `document.createElement` in the Puppeteer console, I get this:

`Proxy {length: 1, name: "createElement"}`

But, when I do the same in Chrome, it's a regular function, not a proxy.

Is there a way I can get Puppeteer to act the same way as Chrome and make the `document` object writable?

Edit:

I've already tried this, but it didn't work. `document.createElement` is still a proxy.

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    document.createElement = document.__proto__.createElement;
})
```

Comment: What if you do the restoration of `createElement` right before the parsing itself?

Comment: Can you elaborate? restoration at what point during the lifecycle? Also I need JS on the page to run first before doing any parsing

Comment: do you have control of the page being parsed? perhaps theres another way to implement that functionality?

Comment: btw question author has already raised the question specifically with the fine folks maintaining puppeteer, which is probably the best way to get the issue resolved officially, https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7402

Comment: @Luke thanks for pointing out that link, to your first question, unfortunately there's no control over the page

Comment: at this point, it may even be quicker for you to contribute to puppeteer to fix, or to try an alternative headless browser, selenium, etc :( best of luck to you!